# Javascript not works after Wordpress migrating

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need your help.

I have a test site in `sitename.domainname.net`, I migrated to `domainname.com` but now the JavaScript codes not works properly, and de Chrome console not show any error. Is the exactly same code.

*credentials removed*

Comment: Why are you publishing your website and credentials?!?! You should never do this. And nobody should have to login to your site to help you with a programming question.

Comment: I removed your site name and login credentials. If you want programming help, great: Edit your question, include your code,  where you think there might be an issue, errors, etc. Again, nobody is going to login to your site and start examining your hosted JavaScript code.

Comment: Oh sorry. But how can you help me? Are the same codes in the two sites, and the Chorme Console not shows errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve it. I don't know why in the new domain not shows me the errors. But I'd try with Firefox and this shows me the error.